# Application Gateway Listeners only allow up to 5 host names

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have a large amount of HTTPS-enabled custom domains (over 600) that I want to route through my Application Gateway service on Azure.

I can pack up to 100 domains into each TSL certificate, and was hoping to create an HTTPS Listener in Application Gateway for each of them. However, the Application Gateway Listener only allows you to specify up to 5 hostnames!

If anyone has a workaround I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Azure Front Door.  Azure Front Door allows up to 500 domains on the Premium subscription. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/includes/front-door-limits.md#azure-front-door-standard-and-premium-tier-service-limits